# How to allow (click) function to have multiple parameters?

Tags: angular

Im trying to add multiple parameters on my click event but its giving this error:

> Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Unexpected end of expression: 
>       submoduleClicked(submodule.submodule_module_id.id, at the end of the 
>       expression [submoduleClicked(submodule.submodule_module_id.id,] in 
>       ng:///CoursemoduleModule/SubmoduleListComponent.html@19:15 ("
>
> > ]submoduleClicked(submodule.submodule_module_id.id, submodule.id)>
> >                       {{submodule.submodule_title}}"): 
> >         ng:///CoursemoduleModule/SubmoduleListComponent.html@19:15

**my service**

```
getSubModule(id:number, submodule_id:number) {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}${id}/submodule/${submodule_id}/`, {headers: this.headers});
```

**coursemodule.component.ts**

```
getContents(coursemodule, submodule) {
    this.coursemoduleService.getSubModule(coursemodule, submodule).subscribe(
      content => {
        this.contents = content;
        console.log(content);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
     );
  }
}
```

**coursemodule.component.ts**

```
submoduleClicked(coursemodule,submodule) {
    console.log(coursemodule,submodule)
  }
```

**coursemodule.component.html**

```
<a (click)=submoduleClicked(submodule.submodule_module_id.id, submodule.id)>    
  {{submodule.submodule_title}}
</a>
```

If I put 1 parameter on my click event, it works fine but the second parameter would be null. I need both parameters.

Comment: In html, try adding quotation marks. (click)="submoduleClicked(submodule.submodule_module_id.id, submodule.id)"

Comment: @jacop41 can you also help me out on my coursemodule.component.ts: how do I pass two parameters in emit? `submoduleClicked(coursemodule,submodule) {
    this.getContents.emit(coursemodule, submodule);
    console.log(coursemodule,submodule)
  }`

Comment: @yulgurz instead of passing two parameters in emit pass a custom JSON object like 
{ courseModule: value,
subModule: value }
and fetch the value by using keys courseModule and subModule

Comment: @Aniket Thanks Man! I also changed my getContents functions parameters to accept json object to `getContents({coursemodule, submodule})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correction of code is add the quotation marks

```
<a (click)="submoduleClicked(submodule.submodule_module_id.id, submodule.id)">    
  {{submodule.submodule_title}}
</a>
```